# Use probsoln for non-latin characters

Tags: probsoln

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[answers, usedefaultargs]{probsoln}
\PSNrandseed{\time}
\begin{document}
\newproblem*{1}{%
  This is Q1}
\newproblem*{2}{%
  This is Q2 करमल}
\newproblem*{3}{%
  This is Q3}
\useproblem{1}

\useproblem{2}

\useproblem{3}
\end{document}
```

`\useproblem{2}` does not include the non-latin characters when compiled with xelatex or lualatex.

How do I typeset questions with non-latin text?

Comment: Does your font support those characters? If not you need to change to another font for the non-latin characters.

Comment: @TeXnician Yes, indeed. Thanks. I added `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\newfontfamily\deva{Lohit Devanagari}`. And added `{\deva करमल}`. And that did the trick. Will you please post this as an answer? I will, then, accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that by default Latin Modern will be loaded, a font that does not support Devanagari (afaik). So you need to add a font that does have the characters you need (e.g. using `fontspec`). Then those non-latin characters need to be set using the other font.